# Checking and removing ressources from CloudFormation template automatically #20611

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-sam

Is there any ways of excluding some ressources that are in a template from a sam deploy command ?

I mean, it would work like a sam validate but with a modification of the template if it doesn't fit with my rules.

For example, I want to check if my CloudFormation template does have a  `"Type": "AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline"`  section, and remove it if it does.

Do you have any tools or use of parameters that could achieve that ? It could also happend in the CDK Synth command because that's how i'm generating templates (code is hardly editable), or in the sam deploy command (or any other library).

For information, i'm also running my stack deploys commands from a GitLab runner, therefore I cannot Prompt it.

Thanks !

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but I had to extract something from the template after the synth. I don't know Your setup, but maybe the solution I found for my problem can be useful also in Your's use case.

I had a `CodePipeline` written in CDK of course. This pipeline had the synth step in which the standard installing and synthesizig stuff was made. I extracted the standard commands to a `synth.sh` file and extended this file by the commands I needed for the extraction. I've used `jq` for that. `jq` is a very powerful CLI-Tool for JSON handling, so You can use it with Your's `template.json`. `CodeBuild` contains `jq` by default.

For the scenario You provided it would be something like this:

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

npx cdk synth
fileName=$(find . -name "*.template.json") #find the template file
jq '(del(.Resources | .[] | select(.Type=="AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline")))' $fileName > newTemplate.json #or $fileName if You want to override the template
```

And for other Types exactly the same way. You can define a `JSON` file in which You can specify what should be deleted and iterate over the file entries using `jq` again.

Comment: Thank you very much, seems like a good solutions :)